# Pandas create buckets depending on the values of a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math

```
      Sales
0       10
1      150
2     1800
3    25000
4  3000000
```

consider above pandas dataframe, I need a function which adds a new column called bubblesize which can have a value between a min and max range and a step size of 4.
for example if I pass min bubble size as 12 and max bubble size as 32 and step size as 4, I should get the below output

```
   Sales  bubble_size
0       10          12
1      150          20
2     1800          24
3    25000          28
4  3000000          32
```

Comment: If step size is 4, shouldn't the row at index 1 be 16?

Comment: @not_speshal looks like a min/max rescaling

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is some kind of scaling:

```
start, stop = 12, 32
step = 4

s = np.log(df['Sales'])
s2 = (s-s.min())/(s.max()-s.min())
df['bubble_size'] = np.ceil((s2*(stop-start)+start)/step)*step
```

Output:

```
     Sales  bubble_size
0       10         12.0
1      150         20.0
2     1800         24.0
3    25000         28.0
4  3000000         32.0
```